# Databinding to a controller inside a directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to angular and have the following directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: '/views/partial-views/partial.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller : function(){
        age : '5'
      },
      controllerAs : 'myCtrl'
    };
  });
```

I want to include the age on my page inside partial.html which looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as s">
    {{s.age}}
</div>
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got Object
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why does partial contain `ng-app`? But anyway remove `ng-controller` declaration and try `myCtrl.age`

Comment: That's a good point I did that just because it is a slightly contrived example. When I don't reference a controller I get no errors however age doesn't appear on the page when I reference it like {{myCtrl.age}}.

Comment: I am not sure why is even not throwing error, it should be `this.age=5` not `age:5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues with you code. Firstly you don't to alias the controller again, by using `ng-controller` in your template so that needs to be removed.

Secondly the controller is a function not object, so use:

`this.age = '5';`

Answer (score 2):

What Chandermani mentioned is absolutely correct. To be more precised, it can be written as,

**Directive Definition**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/views/partial-views/partial.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.age = '5'
            }]
    };
})
```

**Usage**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-directive>
    {{age}}
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

However, there's no meaning of defining a directive here. You can just use a controller definition to fulfill the same action.